# <br> tag in ng-repeat angular-js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat `<ul>` list.
I want to insert `<br>` after each `<ul>` tag.
How can i do this?.

Here is my code

```
<ul class="list" ng-repeat="result in results">
    <li class="list__header">{{$index+1}}</li>
    <li class="list__item">{{result.name}}</li>
    <li class="list__item">{{result.address}}</li>
    <li class="list__item">{{result.phone_number}}</li>
</ul><br><br>
```

The above `<br>` is not renderd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
    <ul class="list" ng-repeat-start="result in results">
                   <li class="list__header">{{$index+1}}</li>
                   <li class="list__item">{{result.name}}</li>
                   <li class="list__item">{{result.address}}</li>
                    <li class="list__item">{{result.phone_number}}</li>
    </ul><br><br ng-repeat-end />
```

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a custom directive for this purpose:

```
 .directive("insertAfter", function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            content: "@"
        }, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.after(scope.content);
        }
    }
  });
```

Then use it inside of your list:

```
<ul class="list" ng-repeat="result in photos" insert-after content="<br>">...</ul>
```